# Websockets - whenever a message is sent from Node WS server, it causes all React clients to refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket

I've been struggling with this for way too long now.  I have a Node server with websockets sending and receiving messages to and from React clients.  But for some reason, whenever a websocket message is sent from Node, it causes all the React clients to refresh their top level component.  So if someone is in the middle of something on a client, it messes them up.  I don't even know how to tell if this is an issue with my Node code or my React code or both.

The React code is huge and a rabbit hole I don't want to go down if I don't have to.  So I'm going to post the websocket code from my Node server in hopes someone can find something there.  You can let me know if you need to see some React code too.  But I'm hoping it's simply a Node WS issue.

setupWebSocket.js

```
// setupWebSocket.js
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { broadcastPipeline } from './pipeline.js';

import DeviceDetector from 'device-detector-js';

const loginAccounts = [
    { pw: '12345', first: 'First', last: 'Last' },
];

let activeLogins = [];

export const setupWebSocket = (server) => {
    // ws instance
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });


    //handle upgrade of the request
    server.on('upgrade', function upgrade(request, socket, head) {
        try {
            // authentication and some other steps will come here
            // we can choose whether to upgrade or not

            wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function done(ws) {
                wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('upgrade exception', err);
            socket.write('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n');
            socket.destroy();
        }
    });

    const deviceDetector = new DeviceDetector();

    // what to do after a connection is established
    wss.on('connection', (ctx, req) => {
        const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];
        const device = deviceDetector.parse(userAgent);

        // print number of active connections
        console.log('Client connected!');
        console.log('connected ', wss.clients.size);
        // if it is an ipad, save that info with the client
        if (device.device.brand === 'Apple' && device.os.name === 'Mac') {
            ctx.deviceType = 'ipad';
        } else if (device.os.name === 'Windows') {
            ctx.deviceType = 'pc';
        } else {
            ctx.deviceType = 'other';
        }

        console.log('clients: ', wss.clients instanceof Set);

        const clientsArr = Array.from(wss.clients);
        const numberIpads = clientsArr.filter(
            (c) => c.deviceType === 'ipad'
        ).length;

        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
            client.send(
                JSON.stringify({
                    eventType: 'clientConn',
                    numberClients: wss.clients.size,
                    device,
                    numberIpads
                })
            );
        });

        // handle message events
        // receive a message and echo it back
        ctx.on('message', (message) => {
            console.log('raw message: |' + message + '|');
            try {
                const jsonMessage = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(message.trim()));
                console.log(`Received message => ${jsonMessage}`);
                console.log('Received JSON: ', jsonMessage);
                //ctx.send(`you said ${message}`);
                if (jsonMessage.eventType === 'movedOrder') {
                    const movedOrder = jsonMessage.movedOrder;
                    console.log('movedOrder: ', movedOrder);
                    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                        let fromMe = false;
                        if (client === ctx) {
                            fromMe = true;
                        }
                        const sendToAllMsg =
                            'Order ' +
                            movedOrder.orderNumber +
                            ' was moved to line ' +
                            movedOrder.lineNumTo +
                            ' pos ' +
                            movedOrder.linePosTo +
                            '!!';
                        // for now we are sending this message to all other
                        // clients besides the originator because it is causing
                        // a refresh when sending to the originating client
                        if (!fromMe) {
                            client.send(
                                JSON.stringify({
                                    eventType: 'movedOrder',
                                    movedOrder: {
                                        orderID: movedOrder.orderNumber,
                                        lineNumTo: movedOrder.lineNumTo,
                                        linePosTo: movedOrder.linePosTo,
                                        lineNumFrom: movedOrder.lineNumFrom,
                                        linePosFrom: movedOrder.linePosFrom
                                    },
                                    msg: sendToAllMsg,
                                    fromMe
                                })
                            );
                        } else {
                            client.send('moved order!');
                        }
                    });
                } else if (jsonMessage.eventType === 'clientLoggedIn') {
                    const pw = jsonMessage.pw;
                    const login = loginAccounts.find((la) => la.pw === pw);
                    if (login) {
                        if (!activeLogins.includes(ctx?.login?.pw)) {
                            // save that login with the client
                            ctx.login = login;
                            activeLogins.push(login.pw);
                        }
                        if (
                            activeLogins.length > 0 &&
                            activeLogins.some((l) => l !== login.pw)
                        ) {
                            // another user is logged in, send warning message
                            const numLogins = activeLogins.filter(
                                (l) => l !== login.pw
                            ).length;
                            let msg = 'There is already 1 user';
                            if (numLogins > 1) {
                                msg = `There are already ${numLogins} users`;
                            }
                            msg += ' (';

                            activeLogins
                                .filter((l) => l !== login.pw)
                                .forEach((l) => {
                                    const theLogin = loginAccounts.find(
                                        (la) => la.pw === l
                                    );
                                    msg += theLogin.first + ' ' + theLogin.last[0];
                                });
                            msg +=
                                ') logged in to the Scheduling.  Be careful about moving orders around.';
                            console.log('sending msg to the client: ' + msg);
                            ctx.send(
                                JSON.stringify({
                                    eventType: 'multipleLogins',
                                    msg
                                })
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });

        // handle close event
        ctx.on('close', () => {
            if (ctx.login) {
                activeLogins = activeLogins.filter(function(e) {
                    return e !== ctx.login.pw;
                });
            }
            console.log('removed - activeLogins: ', activeLogins);
            console.log('closed', wss.clients.size);

            const clientsArr = Array.from(wss.clients);
            const numberIpads = clientsArr.filter(
                (c) => c.deviceType === 'ipad'
            ).length;

            wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                client.send(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        eventType: 'clientConn',
                        numberClients: wss.clients.size,
                        device,
                        numberIpads
                    })
                );
            });
            //clearInterval(interval);
        });

        //sent a message that we're good to proceed
        //ctx.send('connection established.');
    });
};
```

I did have code in my React that was "receiving" the Node messages and handling them appropriately, but I commented that code out and I am still having the refresh issue.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!!

**Update:** With some help from Daniele in the comments, I figured out that it was actually client side code receiving the message that was causing the refresh.  Upon commenting that code out, no refresh happened.

Here is that code in my top level component being loaded directly from app.js:

```
    const ws = useGlobalWebSocketContext();

    const numberClients = parseInt(
        useGlobalWSDataContext().numberClients,
        10
    );

    const numberIpads = parseInt(
        useGlobalWSDataContext().numberIpads,
        10
    );
    console.log('SchedulePage numberIpads: ' + numberIpads);
```

And I actually, I removed everything but the first line, and the refresh still happened!

So figured you all might want to see the web socket context file.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import useWebSocketLite from '../components/home/webSocketHook';

const GlobalWebSocketContext = createContext();

export const useGlobalWebSocketContext = () =>
    useContext(GlobalWebSocketContext);

// websocket stuff
const wsURL =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? 'ws://localhost'
        : 'ws://production.app.local';

const GlobalWebSocketContextProvider = (props) => {
    const websocket = useWebSocketLite({
        socketUrl: wsURL + ':' + process.env.REACT_APP_WS_PORT
    });

    return (
        <GlobalWebSocketContext.Provider value={websocket}>
            {props.children}
        </GlobalWebSocketContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And with that webSocketHook.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// small utilities that we need
// handle json messages
const formatMessage = (data) => {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
        return data;
    }
};

// get epoch timestamp
const getTimestamp = () => {
    return new Date().getTime();
};

// define a custom hook
// accept the url to connect to
// number of times the hook should retry a connection
// the interval between retries
const useWebSocketLite = ({
    socketUrl,
    retry: defaultRetry = 3,
    retryInterval = 1500
}) => {
    // message and timestamp
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    // send function
    const [send, setSend] = useState(() => () => undefined);
    // state of our connection
    const [retry, setRetry] = useState(defaultRetry);
    // retry counter
    const [readyState, setReadyState] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log('socketUrl: ' + socketUrl);
        const ws = new WebSocket(socketUrl);
        ws.onopen = () => {
            // console.log('Connected to socket');
            setReadyState(true);

            // function to send messages
            setSend(() => {
                return (data) => {
                    try {
                        const d = JSON.stringify(data);
                        ws.send(d);
                        return true;
                    } catch (err) {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
            });

            // receive messages
            ws.onmessage = (event) => {
                //const msg = formatMessage(event.data);
                // setData({ message: msg, timestamp: getTimestamp() });
                setData({ message: event.data });
                // console.log(event.data);
            };
        };

        // on close we should update connection state
        // and retry connection
        ws.onclose = () => {
            setReadyState(false);
            // retry logic
            if (retry > 0) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setRetry((retry) => retry - 1);
                }, retryInterval);
            }
        };
        // terminate connection on unmount
        return () => {
            ws.close();
        };
        // retry dependency here triggers the connection attempt
    }, [retry]);

    return { send, data, readyState };
};

export default useWebSocketLite;
```

Comment: The only thing we can say is that every message of type `movedOrder` received from the server will cause a message of type `movedOrder` to be sent to all the clients. Probably the problem is on client. Could you please provide the code of the component with the issue and the code handling `movedOrder` wss messages?

Comment: I can add in the component with the issue, but it is massive.  I have zero code in my client handling the wss messages.  That is what is so confusing to me.  I don't know why the React component should be refreshing whenever Node sends a message.

Comment: And it's not just `movedOrder`, `clientConn` causes the refresh too.

Comment: The problem must be with the client, from your description. And even if you have "zero code in (the) client handling the wss messages", you surely have some code which connects to the websocket server, otherwise nothing would happen at all. It's possible that that code is somehow causing the issue - we can't possibly know without seeing it.

Comment: You are 100% correct!  I did find some front end JS code I forgot about that was connecting to the wss and receiving the message.  Once I commented that out, the refresh no longer happened!  I will post the offending JS code.  This helped.

Comment: So, it seems you found and fixed by yourself the problem in the code handling wss messages (all messages, not only `movedOrder` ones). Isn't it?

Comment: Well, I haven't fixed anything.  I've merely isolated the issue better.

Comment: Is it correct if I say that commenting out the line `const ws = useGlobalWebSocketContext();` the refresh disappear?

Comment: Every time you receive new data `ws.onmessage` is called which in turn calls `setData` which changes the state, if `useGlobalWebSocketContext` is used in the top level component, then it's normal that this component will re-render

Comment: Where is `GlobalWebSocketContextProvider` called / used? Sorry but we are still missing some relevant part of your client

Comment: @MohamedRamrami That was it!  I never thought about moving the WS calls down to a lower component!  If you post your comment as  full blown answer, I will mark it as such.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @dmikester1 Glad it helped. I did post the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you receive new data `ws.onmessage` is called which in turn calls `setData` which changes the state, if `useGlobalWebSocketContext` is used in the top level component, then it's normal that this component will re-render